# Can you find Yenna's mother?

Tags: baldurs-gate-3

Besides Yenna's plot involvement in the camp, is there supposed to be a questline for finding her mother? I never really agreed to help her so maybe that's why I don't have anything related to that (and if that's the case how could I initiate such quest afterwards?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**No,** you cannot find Yenna's mother. Nor is there a quest to attempt to do so.

The presumed "why" is actually pretty interesting, and it's entirely because of the particular role Yenna plays in the overall plot -- she's there as a schrödinger's trojan horse.

Act 3 Spoilers

> During Act 3, Orin, a Changeling, steals one of your party members and
>  holds them captive. There are three criteria:

> - The captured party member can't be a member of the active party;

> - The captured party member must be Lae'zel, Halsin|Minthara, or Gale;

> - The captured party member can't be romanced by the player

> These requirements are actually pretty strict - it's easy to deny Orin
>  a victim. In such scenarios, Yenna is the fallback, with Orin
>  capturing her instead (and murdering poor Grub the cat).

> This does lead to some strangeness though -- Yenna disappears from
>  your camp once Orin's machinations are revealed, even if a valid
>  companion was found. There's no follow-up in that case; Yenna is
>  simply *gone*.

> In short, Yenna is the backup resolution to ensure the game plot progresses normally. The fact that her mother is missing simply gives her the plausible deniability to insert herself innocuously into your camp.

Comment: Couldn't figure out how to get better formatting what with the spoilers and all -- if there's a better way, I'd appreciate a gussying up!

Comment: This reads like an answer to "Where is Yenna" rather than "Where is Yennas MOTHER". You don't answer the question if there is a quest related to the mother.

Comment: Yeah, I appreciate the details but the focus was on her mother since that was the whole reason she even joined. On an unrelated note, I never seemed to lose Yenna despite triggering all these events - in fact she's still making soup in all my camps towards the ending.

Comment: Should have named her Biff.

Comment: My first playthrough I took on Yenna but Orin never interacted with her, just snatched Halsin. 2nd playthrough I actively refused Yenna to come along but she showed up anyway. Then Orin killed Yenna _and_ snatched Lae'zel. Also in a latter combat encounter someone raised dead Yenna as a skeleton, so there's now a pile of splatter where she used to stand. Her cat is fine though! Err, yeah this whole thing is pretty glitchy.